# Strange rattling/ticking noise at 90-120+kmh

Tags: chevrolet, ac, rattle, holden

I have a 2008 Chevrolet Caprice similar to the Holden caprice and also the G8 and also the PPV ect.

There’s a ticking/rattle noise from the car when the car reaches a speed of 100+kmh. If I’m sitting in the back the sound gets lower when I put my ear next to the rear vents. The front passengers say the noise is coming from the glove box area. I suspect it’s something to do with the AC. I can tell that the sound is from inside the car. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the HVAC air intake under the hood and up near the firewall.  It's not uncommon to get leaves and other debris in there and these get down into the HVAC fan and can cause this sound.

If there is any debris in there, clean it out.

If it continues then you may need to get under the dash, usually on the passenger side, and remove the fan and clean any debris out of the blower.